# No keyword with name 'Create Session' found robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm new to Robot Framework. When I run ride.py, I'm getting this error.
here is my code:

```
Create Session  chat    ${URL1} headers=${MyHeaders1}
```

Thank you very mych in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you think there should be a keyword named `create session`? Have you created one? Have you imported one in a library or resource file? Please show us a [mcve].

Comment: Can you please share what you are actually trying to do, what still you searched for it and what libraries you are using and how you are importing them.. :? this will help us in finding the actual problem and then only we will be able to solve your issue.

Comment: I'm trying to get API response and all libraries installed through commands.

Libraries are:

Collections
RequestsLibrary
HttpLibrary.HTTP
json
OperatingSystem
Selenium2Library

And Code is:

${headers}= Create Dictionary content-type application/json
${loginparams}= Create Dictionary password ${Adm_User_Psw} userName ${Adm_User_Name} partnerId ${partnerId} role ${role}
${jsonparams}= json.Dumps ${loginparams}
Create Session opt ${URL} headers=${headers}
${get}= Post Request opt /api data=${jsonparams} params=None headers=${headers}
log ${get.json()}

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to use the `requests` library but haven't imported it. I recommend that you read the user guide, especially the part on [importing libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#importing-libraries).

Basically you want to add this in your `*** Settings ***` section:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    RequestsLibrary
```

You may also want to check out the library's Github [README](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/blob/master/README.md), there's a few usage examples in there that will likely help you.

Comment: I imported RequestsLibrary and its properly(showing in black colour). Still im getting that above error

Comment: even adding this library and extended requests library also getting the same error like No keyword with name 'create session' found

Answer (score -1):

I have explain the issue and also the solution.
Problem :

*** Variables ***
${Base_URL}  http://www.thetestingworldapi.com/

*** Test Cases ***
TC001_GetRequest
create session  thetestingworldapi  ${Base_URL}
${response} =  get request  thetestingworldapi  api/studentsDetails

Error in console:  No keyword with name '${response}= get request ggg' found.

To resolve this kind of error just do one change in the code part, am attching silution as well below.

Solution :

*** Variables ***
${Base_URL}  http://www.thetestingworldapi.com/

*** Test Cases ***
TC001_GetRequest
create session  thetestingworldapi  http://www.thetestingworldapi.com/ --- Use the main base url instead of the variable and this will work.
${response} =  get request  thetestingworldapi  api/studentsDetails